# Mechanism of reduction by elemental sodium

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

How exactly does sodium form an alkoxide from an alcohol? I understand the general idea - sodium has a low first ionization energy. Sodium can thus give up its electron to something that'll take it. Sodium can therefore somehow cause hydrogen gas to leave.

How exactly does this mechanism work? I'm imagining that because alcohols are weak acids, that some hydrated protons exist in solution, and that sodium can donate an electron to these hydrated protons, which then can pair up with each other and form hydrogen gas. Is this accurate?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When alcohol molecules adsorb on the surface of the sodium metal, an electron can be transferred from sodium to the alcohol O-H bond with simultaneous disproportionation  (homolytic cleavage) of the O-H bond thereby generating the alkoxide anion and a hydrogen radical.  The hydrogen radical (probably still on or near the metal surface) can then go on to dimerize and produce hydrogen gas.

[image]

**EDIT**: Support of Mechanism

The mechanism proposed above involves a single electron transfer (SET) from sodium.  This is based on the fact that:

- All dissolving (sodium) metal reactions, such as the Birch reduction of alkynes and aromatics, [proceed by the SET mechanism](http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/vlu_organik/radikale/birch_red.vlu.html)
- Other reactions involving sodium metal such as the [acyloin condensation](http://www.metallacycle.com/chemistry/organic/set/), the [pinacol coupling](http://www.metallacycle.com/chemistry/organic/set/), the [Bouveault–Blanc reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouveault%E2%80%93Blanc_reduction), etc., proceed through the SET mechanism
- The reaction of sodium and water still proceeds in the gas phase where ionization seems less likely, but electron transfer still viable.

Searching on-line I found that water can solvate electrons just like ammonia can.  The chief difference being one of stability; in ammonia solvated electrons are stable for days, whereas in water they are stable for less than 1 msec.  Given the preceding mechanistic evidence and the fact that solvated electrons can exist in water, it seems reasonable to suggest that the mechanism of alkoxide formation, when sodium is reacted with an alcohol, also involves the SET mechanism.

Comment: This is an additional pathway to the aforementioned or the exclusive pathway?

Comment: exclusive pathway

Comment: Oops, so we were wrong before?

Comment: I'm not following your last comment.

Comment: Another poster proposed a mechanism that did not involve disproportionation of the alcohol as a result of reaction with sodium.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the reaction of solid sodium metal with organic compounds involves a single electron transfer mechanism involving the metal surface.  I applied the same reasoning here.

Comment: prooflink please?

Comment: Is the other mechanism at least plausible?

Comment: Here's an example of the SET mechanism involving sodium  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouveault%E2%80%93Blanc_reduction  Also, sodium and water react in the vapor phase - it seems less likely ions would be involved in the primary step in the gas phase.

Comment: I believe an SET mechanism is operating, but doesn't that radical anion have nine electrons on oxygen? Is it possible that the first two steps are concerted? The other referenced reactions involve carbonyls with lower lying pi* orbitals. This mechanism must fill in a sigma* orbital if I'm thinking about it correctly.

Comment: Good point jerepierre!  I've been looking into the matter further.  In the case of gaseous water, the thinking is that a solvated sodium atom may insert itself into the O-H bond, then upon interaction with a second sodium atom electron transfer to form a $\ce{Na^{+}Na^{-}}$ entity occurs (vibrational timescale) followed by disproportionation to sodium hydroxide and sodium hydride.  I'm wondering if "insertion" might be the same as orbital interaction between the sodium AO and oxygen lone pair orbital to form a lower (then sigma*) energy orbital that can hold the ninth electron.

Comment: still can't see any proof. Links to readuction of compounds with double bond are irrelevant by definition, as such compounds have low-level unoccupied orbitals. I downvote the answer as misleading.

Comment: @permeakra  Thanks for sharing your view.  I would say that calling my answer "misleading" may be harsh.  I spent a considerable amount of time researching the problem, and like so often in organic chemistry, and particularly with reactions involving metals, the precise details of the mechanism are still being explored.  Nonetheless, I tried to fashion together what I had learned in order to offer a reasonable answer.  I presume you find the alternate answer less misleading and more accurate since you did not downvote it.

Answer (score 0):

The alcohol splits like this:
$$ROH\rightarrow RO^-+H^+$$
since the pka of alcohol is around 15-17 and then a redox reaction happens:
$$2Na+2H^+\rightarrow 2Na^++H_2$$
Since $H_2$ is released it is entropically favourable and drives the reaction.
Better, alkoxide is represented as:
$$RO^-Na^+$$

Comment: I think you dropped a charge on the second equation. You're now missing a charge on the right side.

Comment: Are you sure ions can't exist in isolation in solution? I'm guessing you're saying there's always some ion pairing going on?

Comment: @Dissenter no it is not always true, i was also told that ions do not exist in isolation until i studied ionic equilibrium

Comment: Okay! So ions can exist in isolation? Also your second equation is still not balanced for charge.

Comment: Also hmm now that I've thought of it this mechanism makes sense since the reaction of sodium with water produces hydrogen gas. The protons came from the auto-ionization of water in that case.

Comment: @Dissenter yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

I think that the sodium when it dissolves in either water or an alcohol will form solvated electrons. These solvated electrons will react with water or the alcohol in reactions such as

e- + H2O --> H + OH-

The hydrogen atoms can then dimerise.

The chemistry of solvated electrons in various media has been studied at great length by pulse radiolysis, this is an experiment similar to flash photoylsis. Instead of a flask of light to start the reaction the pulse radiolysis method normally uses a pulse of high energy electrons from a LINAC.

This article in Chemistry World sheds some light on the reaction of sodium metal with water. https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/tamed-sodium-in-water-comes-out-of-the-blue/1017231.article